# How to define variables based on value of another variable

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am new to the forum, so please pardon me if I am not accustomed to the procedures.

My question is as follows:

Suppose I am running a loop in VBA i = 1 to 10
I want to define variables based on number of loops.

That is, if there are 10 loops then there are 10 variables created x1, x2,...., x10
If there are 20 loops, then there are 20 variables created x1, x2, ....., x20.

I am pretty new to VBA and do not have much idea.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of having a bunch of variables look into using an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of how many loops you have, just use that info to define an array of variables.

For example:

```
Dim numbers(1 To 10) As Long 'declare the upper/lower bounds
Dim morenumbers(20) As Long 'default starts with 0 as lower bound
```

Now if you want to declare values through a loop, that is easy. Let's say you want an array of 10 strings, foo1-foo10:

```
Dim arrayOfFoo(1 To 10) As String

For i = 1 To 10
    arrayOfFoo(i) = "foo" & i
Next
```

Hope that helps.